# Android app auto update on Google Play and permissions change

Tags: google-play, auto-update, android-permissions

I know that when at least one new permission is added, the app will not be auto-updated. The user has to manually update it. 
You will have "Manual Update" when the app's permissions have changed.

What about removing a permission ? 
My current app **version N** is released. In the next release, one permission is removed.
Will the users of **version N** get an automatic update ?

**Edit :** https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/why-do-some-of-my-apps-show-update-and-some-show-update-manual

Comment: I know this is old, but I came across it and wanted to add a minor correction - the app won't be auto-updated if you add at least one new permission *group*. See [About app permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en) where it says "Permissions groups you've already accepted for that app: You won't need to review or accept these permissions again." So if the user has already accepted one 'location' permission, adding another won't require a manual update. I just confirmed this by testing with a dummy app on the play store.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Whenever you see an app that requires manual updates, it’s because the
>   app requires additional permissions. Usually, the app’s developers
>   added a new feature that requires a new permission.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/app-permissions-work-care-android/

So removing a permission will not cause manual update.

Comment: have you confirmed this? "should not" doesn't make me feel 100% comfortable. Thanks!

Comment: sorry to revive an oldddd thread
say i added a camera permission in one update
many users didnt get auto update but got manual update and didnt even update
we push another update with removal of camera permission, will auto update work now  for those un-updated users? 
Thanks and hope u dont mind me hijacking ..

Comment: This is very old post. Now most permission are requested at runtime

Answer (score 1):

In my tests, the following do *not* require manual updates:

- Removing permission
- Adding redundant permission (e.g. READ_STORAGE when WRITE_STORAGE was already specified)