# Auto update app

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an App on google play. I have submitted  the version 1.1 of the application to Play Store. I have a few questions regarding the update

Will the user who has downloaded the app will get the update automatically ? or Do I need to something so that app automatically gets updated on the devices it is installed.

Comment: Yes they will get the update automatically.Just you need to change the version from 1.1 to 1.2,1.3,etc....(not below the released app) for further release and make sure the target sdk and min sdk version are same

Comment: @Kalai. Untrue. There are specific circumstances that have to occur before auto update occurs.

Comment: I agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400305/android-app-auto-update-on-google-play-and-permissions-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the permissions are the same in the previous and new versions and also that the new version still targets the users device, the app will auto update only if the user has opted into having your app auto update.

The user will be offered the update if they have not opted in to auto updates but can decline.

Comment: I have added a extra permission

Comment: Then the app will never auto update as the new permissions have to be authorised by the user.