# Will asking VIBRATE permission on upgrading an app prevent auto update?

Tags: android, google-play

I've added this to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I am wondering whether this will disable auto update for my current users. 
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400305/android-app-auto-update-on-google-play-and-permissions-change) says asking for redundant permissions will not require manual update. So I wonder will VIBRATE prevent auto update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will still auto update. The permission `android.permission.VIBRATE` is not a [dangerous permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous), and even if it were you would only have to ensure you are correctly requesting that permission when required.

From [this google support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=en)

> For apps built for Android 6.0 and up: You won't need to review or accept permission changes for the app to update. The first time you use a feature that uses a new permission, you can allow or deny the use of that data or capability.